# Compaction in Impala Tables

Tags: cloudera, impala

I want to know about the compaction in Impala tables but can't find material to study about.
What are different techniques and where I can find material to study about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principal technique for `compaction` is to avoid the `small file problem` and it depends of your use case.

For example, you could have a process that is writing small files into `HDFS` and you want to query those files like an `Impala table`. You could  have a `staging table` for these small files and load the `base table`  using `INSERT INTO TABLE base_table SELECT .....FROM stg_table` to  compact the tiny files into bigger files.

Another use case would be with `partitioning`.
A major risk when using partitioning is creating partitions that lead you into the small files problem.
When this happens, partitioning a table will actually worsen query performance
(the opposite of the goal when using partitioning) because it causes too many small files to be created.
This is more likely when using `dynamic partitioning`, but it could still
happen with `static partitioning`—for example if you added a new partition to a sales table
on a daily basis containing the sales from the previous day,
and each day’s data is not particularly big.

When choosing your partitions, you want to strike a happy balance between too many partitions
(causing the small files problem) and too few partitions (providing performance little benefit).
The partition column or columns should have a reasonable number of values
for the partitions—but what you should consider reasonable is difficult to quantify.

Using `dynamic partitioning` is particularly dangerous because if you're not careful,
it's easy to partition on a column with too many distinct values.
Imagine a use case where you are often looking for data that falls within
a time frame that you would specify in your query.
You might think that it's a good idea to partition on a column that pertains to time.
But a `TIMESTAMP` column could have the time to the nanosecond, so every row could have a unique value;
that would be a terrible choice for a partition column! Even to the minute or hour could create
far too many partitions, depending on the nature of your data;
partitioning by larger time units like day, month, or even year might be a better choice.

The reading above it's only an introduction of the problem, there are more many use cases and the general topic is performance and tuning.

You could get a start from the Cloudera documentation. You could follow this link:

[Tuning Impala for Performance](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/impala_performance.html)

Hope this helps.