# why it is too slow when insert hdfs hive partitioned table?

Tags: hive, hdfs, cloudera, impala

I ve created table like this: (non partioned)

```
create external table `ersin_db`.`DW_ETL`
  (
  `ID` INT, 
  `NAME` STRING
  )  
    stored as parquet
    LOCATION '/user/ers/ersyn61/'
    tblproperties('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY');
```

when I try insert it is fast.

but when I create partitioned table like this:

```
create external table `ersin_db`.`DW_ETL`
  (
  `ID` INT, 
  `NAME` STRING
  ) 
partitioned by(partition_etldate_string string )
    stored as parquet
    LOCATION '/user/ers/ersyn61/'
    tblproperties('parquet.compression'='SNAPPY');


SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
set hive.optimize.sort.dynamic.partition=true;
```

the insert is slow?

How can I it faster?

thanks in advance

Comment: How are you trying to insert records? there are many ways.

Comment: with odbc via informatica

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how that works. Do you have to set up a ````sql insert statement```` in Informatica? if so, what kind of ````sql insert statement````? On the other hand, what kind of ````partition```` have you choosen? to understand what I say you could follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646565/compaction-in-impala-tables/62677047#62677047 about ````Compaction in Impala Tables````

Comment: the thing I dont understand is why it is fast when it is non partitioned table

Comment: It probably could be because of the size of the batches. Surely in ````no-partitioned-table```` the size of the batch is bigger than in ````partitioned-table````

Comment: How can I change it ?

Comment: I don't know how ````Informatica```` chunks the data, I would imagine by ````partition column````, because of the behavior you are describing,  but I don't really know, and I don't know if you  can change that behavior. And this is related to the link I put previously. The partition column or columns should have a reasonable number of values for the partitions, and I think it could be the size of the batch, the number of values per partition, but I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think i can answer to this.
Your second table is a dynamic partitioned table. While inserting into a dynamically partitioned table, hive sort the final data and write into each partition one by one(default behaviour). Since, you partitioned on `partition_etldate_string` it takes a lot of time to insert into each partition one by one. here is a typical SQL summary when it tries to insert into a dynamically partitioned table on year,month. Notice, how `SORT` operation is taking 17min while data processing is taking only 1min.

```
Operator       #Hosts  Avg Time  Max Time   #Rows  Est. #Rows  Peak Mem  Est. Peak Mem  Detail                                                                                          
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
02:SORT             2    17m16s    30m50s  55.05M          -1  25.60 GB       12.00 MB                                                                                                  
01:EXCHANGE         2   9s493ms  12s822ms  55.05M          -1  26.98 MB        2.90 MB  HASH(CAST(extract(ts, 'year') AS SMALLINT),CAST(extract(ts, 'month') AS TINYINT)) 
00:SCAN HDFS        2  51s958ms     1m10s  55.05M          -1  76.06 MB      704.00 MB  default.my_table
```

Your first table is not partitioned so hive wont sort the data and write one partition at a time but it will write all data together.

Depending on volume of data, dynamic partition can take a lot of time to load. This is a default behavior and i am not sure how to put a workaround this. You can use static partition but it will be difficult to handle partitions based on date.